# neo4j relationship type limit?

Tags: neo4j

I've created my graph with 38,000 relationship types, essentially shifting information out of properties and onto the relationship type. I've done this because for my query speed, the `.getProperties()` functions was holding me back. But now when I attempt to run my query, I instead get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.receiveRelationships(NodeManager.java:658)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.getMoreRelationships(NodeManager.java:624)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getMoreRelationships(NodeImpl.java:400)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.loadInitialRelationships(NodeImpl.java:352)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.ensureRelationshipMapNotNull(NodeImpl.java:338)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getAllRelationshipsOfType(NodeImpl.java:184)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeImpl.getRelationships(NodeImpl.java:269)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.getRelationships(NodeProxy.java:114)
```

I'm assuming this is related to the large number of relationship types I have, as before expanding to 38,000, I didn't have any problems. Is there any way to remedy this? Is there a place where I can see the limitations of the Relationship Types for neo4j?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is probably right, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/capabilities-capacity.html#capabilities-data

Maybe raise an issue to extend it and your use case? How many do you need?

Comment: I need ~100,000. As said, I've looked through the code and couldn't find any threshold, but I also found that getting properties was actually a very expensive operation. What I kind of need is a `getPropertyMap()` operation, because I'm getting all the properties for my relationships on my query.

Comment: `org.neo4j.kernel.IdType` is the class that I'm refering to. There is a variable `RELATIONSHIP_TYPE` which is (2^16)-1, which should be 65k, but I even bumped it up to 2^20 and I still get the above error.

Comment: That is strange. Can you isolate this in a tiny test and file an issue if that is so?

Answer (score 0):

I believe storage wise the actual limit is 2^15-1 (=32767) types, not 2^16-1 (=65535). There seems to be some invalid checks, making for a weird exception being thrown from Neo4j.

Since you need at least 100k you would still hit a problem. Would be great with a configurable (at store creation) max number of relationship types supported, a setting that would affect the space each relationship will take on disk.

Comment: `(long)Math.pow( 2, bits )-1;` is the line, with bits being 16, at least in 1.8M06, which makes me thing it's 65k, but I even if I bump that line up I still get errors. And for now, I just need to test on 40k, eventually I'll need to support 100k, but I just wanted to test this method for my performance.